# C kbhit() returns 1 even when key is not pressed

Tags: c, kbhit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%d", kbhit());
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed the kbhit() function was going weird in the game I was making so I tried this code.
It printed 0 at the beginning, when the key was not pressed. Then I pressed a key and it printed 1, and continued to print 1 even after I stopped pressing any keys. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DOS api, but I would imagine you'd have to flush the input buffer by reading the input with `getch()` while `kbhit()` returns true.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-160 `If the function returns a nonzero value, a keystroke is waiting in the buffer. The program can then call _getch or _getche to get the keystroke.`

Comment: For a game, why use buffered keyboard input at all?  Consider, just calling [GetKeyboardState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate) on every frame and evaluate the keys you care about.  When I worked in a game studio (ages ago), that's what we used.  Or [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) if your game isn't pumping windows messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It printed 0 at the beginning, when the key was not pressed

`kbhit()` returns zero, if any key is not pressed.

> Then I pressed a key and it printed 1, and continued to print 1 even
> after I stopped pressing any keys. Why is this happening?

**Reason:**  `kbhit()`  is buffered function. So, every keystroke will be sent to the buffer, and processed sequentially. If you donot clear the buffer, same output will be printed by `printf` function. You can flush the buffer to remove the keystroke or use `getch`.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-160